# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-01-01 00:00:00' in Python 3D graph

Tags: python, pandas, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot a 3D graph with date as x-value, temperature as y-value and total energy consumed as z-value. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('floor2.csv')

td = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

td.scatter(df['Date'], df['T_out'].values, df['Total'].values)
td.set_xlabel('Date')
td.set_ylabel('Outdoor Temperature')
td.set_zlabel('Total Consumed Energy')
plt.show()
```

However, I am getting the following error for date value:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Any help, please. Thank you...

Comment: Your `Date`'s specified as a string, which `plt` doesn't know how to order on the axis for a `scatter`. [Convert it to a `Datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: Thank you, I tried to change into datetime but I have the following error as well: ValueError: time data '2019-01-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%d%m:%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @MKhalil try convert it to a datetime without specifying the formatting. df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) Might help assuming the datetime strings are consistent. Otherwise, assuming the timestamp portion doesn't matter, you may have to clean up the string using regex.

Comment: @born_naked can you please tell me how to do the regex thing please

Comment: Probably best as a separate question, but  df['date']= df['date'].str.extract(pat = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')  is something like what you would need. If that works, you should then be able to cast it to a datetime. But, if it doesn't, you should post another question specific to the cast to datetime error and post several rows of actual date values so the answer can sort out what is going on in that column that is irregular.